An explanation on why the two SQL commands is having the same result
I am currently learning SQL commands on Oracle 10g.
I had to write two queries, and both have the same output for some reason. Can you please explain why the two following queries are producing the same output?
SELECT GREATEST (4, 5, 17) FROM DUAL;

SELECT LEAST( '4', '5', '17') FROM DUAL;

Both are producing the same output: 17

Why do you (apparently) think they should not?

HINT: String vs Int

Sorting them alphabetically 17 is the smalest since it starts with 1 and sorting them by value 17 is the greatest

Oh, at first, I thought that the strings were being compared as a whole using ASCII values. I got it now, thanks!

Note that the second query returns '17' (though it might look like 17.)

In the first query:
SELECT GREATEST (4, 5, 17) FROM DUAL;

The three numbers being passed to GREATEST() are being compared numerically, and thus 17 is the greatest number.  However, in the second query:
SELECT LEAST( '4', '5', '17') FROM DUAL;

the three parameters to LEAST() are strings, and therefore are being compared lexicographically.  In this case, the text sorts as '17' being "less" than both '4' and '5', as 1 sorts before strings starting with 2 to 9.

Thanks. I first thought that the strings were being compared using ASCII values, so was confused as to why 17 was coming as the output.

@Rose Please consider marking the Accept Answer flag to let others know this has been resolved.
